# C# Winforms Livecharts: Fire Event when rendering of CartesianChart is finished

Tags: c#, winforms, livecharts

I am using `LiveCharts.WinForms.CartesianChart` to render a large amount of points:

```
myChart.Zoom = ZoomingOptions.X;
myChart.Pan = PanningOptions.X;

myChart.Series.Add(new LineSeries
{
    Values = chartValuesScores,
    Fill = System.Windows.Media.Brushes.Transparent,
    PointGeometrySize = 5
});
myChart.AxisX.Add(new Axis
{
    Labels = labels
});
```

What I want to do is to display some kind of a progressbar and stop the time `LiveCharts` needs to render this points. But it seems that `LiveCharts` renders the points asynchronously. That means that after running the code above, it continues running other code lines and exits the function. 
Thus, my question is: Is there a way to detect that `LiveCharts.WinForms.CartesianChart` is finished with rendering? I could not find an event or something else.

Answer (score 0):

I found this while checking the docs:  https://lvcharts.net/App/examples/v1/wpf/Events

It lists `Chart.UpdaterTick` as one of the events.  That events seems to fire when the graph has finished loading the data and had rendered it on screen, I believe what you were looking for?

I've tested myself and appears to work as I expect.

Answer (score -1):

There is an `CartesianChart.Loaded` event, which is fired after the chart is rendered.

```
myChart.Loaded += myChart_Loaded;

private void myChart_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    // chart is rendered
}
```